# Is it possible to modify this script to add a style to an existing class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm still very inexperienced in jQuery but trying to tackle this issue. I have a hamburger menu that opens and closes when clicked. However, I added CSS to the hamburger menu to expand to 100vh when open. This worked fine, however, the content in the background still scrolls behind the menu. I found CSS that locks the body in place via an **overflow: hidden** styling to the "HTML, body" class and lets me open and close the menu without the background scrolling, but with that CSS styling constantly in place, I cannot scroll at all even when the menu is closed.

This brings me to my question. I believe I found one of the scripts that open and closes the hamburger menu. Would it be possible to modify and add to this script so that it adds the above style to the "HTML, body" class only when the menu is open?

I went through W3 Schools to get a better understanding of the syntax, but this script is a little different than what I saw in the tutorials.

Here is the script:

```
function() {
  return e(".mobile_nav.opened .mobile_menu_bar").not(e(this)).trigger("click"), s.hasClass("closed") ? (s.removeClass("closed").addClass("opened"), n.stop().slideDown(500)) : (s.removeClass("opened").addClass("closed"), n.stop().slideUp(500)), !1
}
```

Is this a possible solution or is there a better option for me to prevent the background scroll? I would share the link but I have to have it hidden an under-construction page.

Here is a screen shot of what I am seeing on my end.

[image: Hamburger menu in question]

Comment: If I understand your question, you wish to *hide* the scrolbar on the right - as shown in your image. Did you try setting your menu to 100wh with z-index higher than body & html? If your menu will *cover* the body, you will get what you need.

Comment: I just realized that I have this menu only displaying for mobile but there are other menus using the same module for different orientations/layouts. If I make edits to this script it would also affect those others. Apologize for this massive question, but how would I also make this sure that this only applies to this one specific menu on the svreen shot?

Comment: Hello Mulli. Thank you for the reply. Let me try this option out. I enjoyed learning that little bit of jQuery on W3, but if I can solve this via CSS I would be ecstatic. haha.

Comment: To apply your solution to mobile only use google "css media query mobile" to find the way - Please note that we are defocusing from your original question.

Comment: I just tried out the recommendation above and realized that the scroll bar isn't on the actual page but rather just browsers scroll bar in the inspector view. The bar is showing up there because the content below the dropdown hamburger menu is still scrollable I believe.